# How to disable the ACR122U buzzer on Mac OS using Mono and C#?

Tags: macos, mono, nfc, smartcard, pcsc

Forgive me for possibly not using the proper terminology, as I’m new to this. I have wrapped the PCSC API and the app now detects cards (using SCardGetStatusChange) without any problems.

Now I’d like to be able to do something as simple as turning off the buzzer. As I understand I first need to call SCardConnect with ShareMode.SCARD_SHARE_DIRECT. This call replies with an OK. After that I use SCardControl to send the following bytes:
FF 00 52 00 00 
(as described in chapter 6.7 of http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.02.pdf)

However, this call returns with -2146435064.
I’m using 0x42000001 for the second parameter of SCardControl. I have tried several other ‘educated guesses’ but all with the same result.

Did anyone ever get this working?

**UPDATE**

No matter what I try, SCardControl keeps returning -2146435064 (SCARD_E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER). The call being made is defined like this:

```
WinSCard.SCardControl (card, controlCode, ref data[0], data.Length, ref responseBuffer[0], responseBuffer.Length, ref responseLength);
```

With the parameters having the following values:

- card = 0x1201a (created by the call to SCardConnect)
- controlCode = 0x42000DAC (0x42000000 | 3500) but as mentioned I have
  tried several other values
- data = byte[] { 0xFF, 0x00, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00}
- responseBuffer = byte[100]

In an attempt to eliminate the possible invalid value of the controlCode I have also tried to use SCardTransmit (using SCARD_PROTOCOL_RAW with SCardConnect), but this results in -2146435050 (SCARD_E_NOT_TRANSACTED)

**UPDATE 2**

Just tried the same code on Raspberry PI (via libpcsclite.so) and it works fine. I would really like to get it running on OS X as well though...

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that at least some of the control commands will only work if there's a card present.

Try running your code with a card present.

This is currently working for my setup, which is a Raspberry Pi and an ACS ACR1252U.